# Hide some products from woo-commerce products list

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a specific product type that I want to hide from Product Listing page for admins. Each product is basically a dynamically created product by our customers. We want to receive orders against them but don't want them to populate our listing here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot, there is not specified particular product hide based on category/Tag-based. You can hide products using the "Catalog Visibility" setting. If the product creating  dynamically then you should pass "catalog visibility" hidden value so that product is not listed

[image]

We can use the following code snippet added to the functions.php file to hide the product from the shop page:

```
/**
 * Hide WooCommerce product by category from the shop page.
 *
 * @param $q
 */



add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'njengah_hide_product_by_category_shop_page' ); 

function njengah_hide_product_by_category_shop_page( $q ) {

    $tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );

    $tax_query[] = array(
           'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
           'field' => 'slug',
           'terms' => array( 'uncategorised','auto-parts'), // Don't display products in the 'auto parts' category on the shop page.
           'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    );


    $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the catalog visibility is already set to hidden. 
I just don't want admins to see it in the dashboard.